# Removing all quotes from Object in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have my original data appearing as

```
var Data = { ques: [], chat1: 'o.chat1', chat2: 'o.chat2' }
```

and i want to remove the single quotes from the field value which make my output appearing without any quotes

```
var newData = { ques: [], chat1: o.chat1, chat2: o.chat2 }
```

Comment: Did you try to print object value `console.log(Data )` ? Quotes indicates that it is a string, do you actually have quotes as a value ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is converting to `String` and replace quotes `"`.

Of course, is your object has another quotes rather than those in your example, you will face other problems.

```js
var Data = { ques: [], chat1: 'o.chat1', chat2: 'o.chat2' }

console.log(JSON.stringify(Data).replace(/\"/g, ""));
```